# Return upper-case letter in s or -1 if none found

Tags: java, string

So, in this java program... I'm trying to return the last letter out of a string. 
The catch is the string could either end in a letter or number. How would I go about doing this?
Also - I've been instructed to return -1 if no letters are found.

```
public static int lastElement(String s) {
    for (int i = s.length(); i >= 0; i--){
        int lastElement = s.indexOf(i);
        char y = s.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isDigit(y)){
            i--;
        }
        else{
            return lastElement;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Use `continue` instead of `i--` and you probably want to `return y` if you want to return the last character, not the index of the last character

Comment: The first character of a string is at index 0. So the last one is at index `length - 1`, not `length`. Also, There are letters, digits, and other kinds of characters. A character not being a digit is not necessarily a letter.

Comment: It's not clear why you're using `indexOf` at all... why aren't you just returning `i`?

Comment: You should also clarify: do you need to return the last letter (i.e. `y`), or the index of the last letter (i.e. `i`)?

Comment: Can't believe I'm helping Sarah Palin! What next? Donald Trump? I'm much too kind.

Comment: @JBNizet Make Donald Drumpf again. http://www.theguardian.com/tv-and-radio/video/2016/mar/02/john-oliver-targets-trump-with-make-donald-drumpf-again-campaign-video

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See my comments inline.

```
public static int lastElement(String s) {
    // the last index is length - 1
    for (int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        // get the character at an index, rather than search for the index
        char ch = s.charAt(i);
        // if it's not a digit
        if (!Character.isDigit(ch)) 
            // return it as an upper case letter.
            return Character.toUpperCase(ch);
        // if it is a digit, you don't need to do anything 
        // as it will go onto the next index anyway.
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Note: you might want to change `if (!Character.isDigit(ch))` with `if (Character.isLetter(ch))`  This is because there are many characters, such as space, which are not digits, nor are they letters.

Comment: @JBNizet I added a note to this effect.  It's not clear to me what the OP wanted in this regard.